# Manual installation of wordpress on IIS shows directory and error

Tags: wordpress, iis, installation

I'm trying to install wordpress locally through IIS.
I have followed instructions from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozPcRpr8Tw&t=1147s) by:

1. installed MySQL, created wordpress schema and user permission.
2. installed php new version.(7.3)
3. downloaded wordpress 5.4 from wordpress website and extract it, copying into C:\inetpub\wwwroot
4. opened IIS, added website and point it to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress, the wordpress folder which I have copied( and I did edit the config file to folow my db usrname and password)
5. once I clicked on the browse through IIS, I can only view directory like page through my browser, like the image below.

[image]

if I click on activate.php or wp-admin/install.php,error page will appear as follows:

[image]

I also found this error when I click on test connection during adding the website in IIS:(I'm not sure whether it is related to the problem)
[image]

So, can anyone help to enlighten me what should I do to bring me to the installation page for the wordpress? Thanks.

Comment: You probably missed tons of steps, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: could you please share that you enabled iis CGI feature or not? instead of manually installing Wordpress you could use iis web platform installer and install Wordpress and PHP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-wordpress-on-iis